# Why is the scss repeat function not working?

Tags: css, sass, compilation

I want to do this in scss `border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170) repeat(3,black) ;`

instead of `border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170) black black black ;`

but when i took a look at the css file, i found that scss compiled it to

`border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170) repeat(3,black) ;`

all the other functions are working perfectly ( lighten() ,darken() ... ).

any idea about the problem ? normally it should work

Comment: @DogukanCavus i used a function directive like montionned in the post solution , but i still don't get why this particular function is not working , while all the others are .

Comment: is the repeat function a built in function in SASS ?

Comment: yes , that's not the first time i'm gonna work with it .

Edit : i just went to the official sass page , but ididn't find the repeat() function , i'm really confused right now .

Comment: I don't think there is any inbuilt repeat() function in sass. Will have to create one.

Comment: i guess i just got confused somehow , the code in the answer works perfectly for me since i only want to repeat property values , not text .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a SASS function that does the job.

```
@function repeater($n, $character) {
    $c: "";

    @for $i from 1 through $n {
        $c: $c +" "+ $character;
    }

    @return unquote($c);
}

// now i can use it :D
border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170) repeater(3, black);
```

Comment: so you confirm the duplicate then?

Comment: I confirmed it , but i used the unquote() function so that i can use it on property values not text .